# None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specific elements:

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

when I activate iCloud under the Capabilities tab I receive this error message when validating an archive:

[image]

When I check the services in the member center, I have iCloud enabled (for the correct Prefix, and App ID)

Under Code Signing, I chose the corresponding Code Signing Identity and the correct provisioning profile.

Can anyone explain and/or help, what is going on there?

Comment: You need to create new iCloud enabled profile (Both developement and Production) from developer portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new iCloud enabled profile (Both developement and Production) from developer portal. Once you do it you should be good to go.